# Draw a line with non-Cartesian coordinates in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphics, line, coordinate-systems

MATLAB's [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) command allows you to pass it optional `X` and `Y` data that specify non-cartesian x-y components. (they essentially change the basis vectors). I desire to pass similar arguments to a function that will draw a line.

**How do I plot a line using a non-cartesian coordinate system?**

My apologies if my terminology is a little off. This still might technically be a cartesian space but it wouldn't be *square* in the sense that one unit in the x-direction is orthogonal to one unit in the y-direction. If you can correct my terminology, I would really appreciate it!

EDIT:

Below better demonstrates what I mean:

The commands:

```
datA=1:10;
datB=1:10;
X=cosd(8*datA)'*datB;
Y=datA'*log10(datB*3);
Z=ones(size(datA'))*cosd(datB);
XX=X./(1+Z);
YY=Y./(1+Z);
surf(XX,YY,eye(10)); view([0 0 1])
```

produces the following graph:

[image: Non-Cartesian Surf]

Here, the X and Y dimensions are not orthogonal nor equi-spaced. One unit in x could correspond to 5 cm in the x direction but the next one unit in x could correspond to 2 cm in the x direction + 1 cm in the y direction. **I desire to replicate this functionality but drawing a line instead of a surf** For instance, I'm looking for a function where:

```
straightLine=[(1:10)' (1:10)'];
my_line(XX,YY,straightLine(:,1),straightLine(:,2))
```

would produce a line that traced the red squares on the surf graph.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. The coordinates to `plot`, much like `surf`, have to be given in a Cartesian coordinate system. However, you can *parametrize* your data, to get `x` and `y` as a function of your own, non-Cartesian coordinates. I mean `phi=linspace(0,2*pi,50); r=cos(phi).^2; x=r.*cos(phi); y=r.*sin(phi); plot(x,y)`. This should be something like `polar(theta,r)`. Disclaimer: I realize that the polar coordinate system is locally orthogonal, but I hope you get my point. So as long as you know the transformation from your custom coordinate system to Cartesian, you should be fine

Comment: Are you possibly looking for something like an [isometric projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection)?

Comment: @beaker, that might work but I'm not projecting from 3D to 2D.

Comment: @chessofnerd I believe that without further details we won't be able to help (beyond what I've written in comment).

Comment: @AndrasDeak, please see my edits.

Comment: Why is `plot([1:5 12 13 14 16 20],[1:5 7 11 12 15 18],'r.-');` not what you need? (The format is arguable, this just helps you see where the points are). If this is not what you need, then you have to explain better what you wish to achieve:)

Comment: Referring to the output of `surf` is especially confusing, since there are no "red dots", only "red rectangles" there. Could you explain what you want in a more unambiguous, mathematical form? And a set of sample input -> expected output pairs?

Comment: @AndrasDeak , that worked perfectly in this simple case. I feel a little dumb I didn't think about it. However, I actually need the more general case where the `X` and `Y` data aren't vectors but matricies. I have re-edited the question to reflect that. Thank you so much for the help you've provided and my apologies for not being able to articulate this as well as I would like to.

Comment: It's OK, I'm not trying to badger you, only trying to reach a point where it's likely that others (including me) will understand what you're after:)

Comment: I added an answer, I think this is what you need. Let me know if something's missing. Also: I think `Z=repmat(cosd(datB),[size(X,1), 1])` might be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not certain of what your input data are about, and what you want to plot. However, from *how* you want to plot it, I can help.

When you call

```
surf(XX,YY,eye(10)); view([0 0 1]);
```

and want to get only the "red parts", i.e. the maxima of the function, you are essentially selecting a subset of the `XX`, `YY` matrices using the diagonal matrix as indicator. So you could select those points manually, and use `plot` to plot them as a line:

```
Xplot = diag(XX);
Yplot = diag(YY);
plot(Xplot,Yplot,'r.-');
```

The call to `diag(XX)` will take the diagonal elements of the matrix `XX`, which is exactly where you'll get the red patches when you use `surf` with the `z` data according to `eye()`.

Result:

[image: result from plot]

---

Also, if you're just trying to do what your example states, then there's no need to use matrices just to take out the diagonal eventually. Here's the same result, using elementwise operations on your input vectors:

```
datA = 1:10;
datB = 1:10;
X2 = cosd(8*datA).*datB;
Y2 = datA.*log10(datB*3);
Z2 = cosd(datB);
XX2 = X2./(1+Z2);
YY2 = Y2./(1+Z2);
plot(Xplot,Yplot,'rs-',XX2,YY2,'bo--','linewidth',2,'markersize',10);
legend('original','vector')
```

Result:
[image: new result]

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for helping me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has many built-in function to assist you.

In 2D the easiest way to do this is `polar` that allows you to make a graph using `theta` and `rho` vectors:

```
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
r = sin(2*theta);
figure(1)
polar(theta, r), grid on
```

So, you would get [this.](https://habrastorage.org/files/15f/736/cd5/15f736cd5cb441dc9eaeceb3d4c017d4.png)
There also is `pol2cart` function that would convert your data into `x` and `y` format:

```
[x,y] = pol2cart(theta,r);
figure(2)
plot(x, y), grid on
```

This would look slightly [different](https://habrastorage.org/files/4b4/778/9af/4b47789affb54c3fbfad5c50c40e9d42.png)
Then, if we extend this to 3D, you are only left with `plot3`. So, If you have data like:

```
theta = linspace(0,10*pi,500);
r = ones(size(theta));
z = linspace(-10,10,500);
```

you need to use `pol2cart` with 3 arguments to produce [this](https://habrastorage.org/files/1b7/719/593/1b7719593e9743118065c5caa8e7a8b2.png):
    [x,y,z] = pol2cart(theta,r,z);
    figure(3)
    plot3(x,y,z),grid on

Finally, if you have spherical data, you have `sph2cart`:

```
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
phi = linspace(-pi/2,pi/2,100);
rho = sin(2*theta - phi);
[x,y,z] = sph2cart(theta, phi, rho);
figure(4)
plot3(x,y,z),grid on
view([-150 70])
```

That would look [this way](https://habrastorage.org/files/ee1/22a/fab/ee122afabf15426688ade050d3786a56.png)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not have polar or spherical data. (However I am trying to do something where this might work)

Comment: The @AndrasDeak 's comment is very useful because it is applicable to any coordinate system. I would also suggest you to provide some sample data. This would help community to understand your question better.